# Libgdx Scene2d and Box2d light

Tags: libgdx, box2d, scene2d

Currently I am using scene2d and I want to implement shadows using Box2d light.
I want shadows under characters but when I draw something after render() , it draws nothing.
 For example, in draw() method of an actor,

```
    public void draw(Batch batch, float delta){
        super.draw(batch,delta);
        ray_handler.render();       
        batch.draw(Something......)
    }
```

[image]

But when draw before render, it shows no problem.

```
    public void draw(Batch batch, float delta){
        super.draw(batch,delta);
        batch.draw(Something......)     
        ray_handler.render();
    }
```

[image: Draw]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The render() methods of ray handler should not in the batch.begin() and batch.end() methods.

```
public void draw(Batch batch, float delta){
    super.draw(batch,delta);
    batch.end(); 
    ray_handler.render();     
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Something......)
}
```

Above codes are working properly.
[The Result looks like this](https://youtu.be/BjKbwa3JxZw)